# What is the significance of the three distinct aspects of the temptation of Eve in the garden?

Tags: exegesis, sin, genesis, temptation

Genesis 3 indicates that there were three distinct aspects of the temptation of Eve:

> So when the woman saw that the tree was **good for food**, and that it was
>   **a delight to the eyes**, and that the tree was to be desired **to make one
>   wise**, she took of its fruit and ate, and she also gave some to her
>   husband who was with her, and he ate.  Genesis 3:6 ESV

Jesus was also tempted in three ways in Matthew 4:

> Then Jesus was led up by the Spirit into the wilderness to be tempted
>   by the devil. And after fasting forty days and forty nights, he was
>   hungry. And the tempter came and said to him, **"If you are the Son of
>   God, command these stones to become loaves of bread."** But he answered,
>   "It is written, "'Man shall not live by bread alone, but by every word
>   that comes from the mouth of God.'"  Then the devil took him to the
>   holy city and set him on the pinnacle of the temple and said to him,
>   **"If you are the Son of God, throw yourself down,** for it is written,
>   "'He will command his angels concerning you,' and "'On their hands
>   they will bear you up, lest you strike your foot against a stone.'" 
>   Jesus said to him, "Again it is written, 'You shall not put the Lord
>   your God to the test.'" Again, the devil took him to a very high
>   mountain and showed him all the kingdoms of the world and their glory.
>   And he said to him, "**All these I will give you, if you will fall down
>   and worship me.**" Then Jesus said to him, "Be gone, Satan! For it is
>   written, "'You shall worship the Lord your God and him only shall you
>   serve.'" Then the devil left him, and behold, angels came and were
>   ministering to him.  Matthew 4:1-11 ESV

Additionally, Jeremiah 9:23-24 speaks of three different things of which men must not boast:

> Thus says the LORD: "Let not the wise man boast in his **wisdom**, let not
>   the mighty man boast in his **might**, let not the rich man boast in his
>   **riches**, but let him who boasts boast in this, that he understands and
>   knows me, that I am the LORD who practices steadfast love, justice,
>   and righteousness in the earth. For in these things I delight,
>   declares the LORD."  Jeremiah 9:23-24 ESV

1 John 2:15-17 also speaks of three things not to love in the world:

> Do not love the world or the things in the world. If anyone loves
>   the world, the love of the Father is not in him. For all that is in
>   the world— **the desires of the flesh** and **the desires of the eyes** and
>   **pride in possessions**—is not from the Father but is from the world.
>   And the world is passing away along with its desires, but whoever
>   does the will of God abides forever.  1 John 2:15-17 ESV

Finally, in the parable of the sower, there are three things that choke the word and make it unfruitful:

> but the cares of the world and the deceitfulness of riches and the
>   desires for other things enter in and choke the word, and it proves
>   unfruitful.  Mark 4:19 ESV

So, each of these identifies three things.  I've wondered if they are all speaking of the same three things, perhaps 1) What I have, 2) What I do, and 3) Who I am.

Is there any historical perspective from church history or any modern commentaries on these three specific aspects of temptation or sin?

Comment: You might be interested in the [evangelical counsels](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4234/what-are-the-evangelical-counsels/4235#4235).  In that answer, there are three more temptations we should avoid.

Comment: Jesus was tempted *more* than merely 3 times - they are merely representative of the entire 40 day period

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **1 Thessalonians 5:23 KJV**
>   And the very God of peace sanctify you
>   wholly; and I pray God your whole spirit and soul and body be
>   preserved blameless unto the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ.

Shameless "copy and paste" from [here](http://www.kjvbible.org/body.html):

> 1: The **BODY**. This is your PHYSICAL component of being. It is flesh
>   made from a collection of unremarkable mineral elements (but is mostly
>   water) and is in harmony with the nature and spirit of this world. It
>   grows, matures, begins to deteriorate, eventually dies, and then
>   decomposes back into its constituent elements and remains a part of
>   the dust of the world. The body is a part of you but is NOT ALL of
>   what defines who YOU are.
>
> > **Proverbs 5:11 KJV**
> >     And thou mourn at the last, when thy flesh and thy body are consumed,"
>
> 2: The **SOUL**. This is who YOU are; it is a part of your SPIRITUAL
>   component. This is your individuality, your "I AM" so to speak (made
>   in God’s image), your "heart." Although your individual soul did not
>   exist before your mother and father procreated you, it will exist
>   forever. It cannot be killed by man:
>
> > **Matt. 10:28 KJV**
> >     And fear not them which kill the body, but are not able to kill the soul: but rather fear him which is able to destroy both soul
> >     and body in hell."
>
> When your body dies your soul (YOU) will leave the body of flesh:
>
> > **Genesis 35:18 KJV**
> >     And it came to pass, as her soul was in departing, (for she died) that she called his name Benoni: but his father called him Benjamin."
>
> 3: The **SPIRIT**. This is the source of power and control for both your
>   body and soul; it is either evil or good, darkness or light, unholy or
>   Holy, unclean or clean, of Satan or of God:
>
> > **Luke 9:55 KJV**
> >     But he turned, and rebuked them, and said, Ye know not what manner of spirit ye are of."

---

Why all that explanation? Well, the Eve's temptation and Jesus temptation are similar:

```
         Eve                        Jesus
Body   - good for food            - stones to become loaves of bread
Soul   - delight to the eyes      - all these I will give you
Spirit - desired to make one wise - If you are the Son of God...
```

(Sorry the formatting, Markdown has not tables)

Satan tempted in all aspects possible both Jesus and Eve - Body, Soul and Spirit.

Finally, not all scholars accept that kind of theory, because consider "Soul" and "Spirit" to be equivalent, or different terms that refers to same subject.

Comment: +1.  Nice setup, and good comparison at the end.  It shows the similarity clearly.  I'd never thought much of it before, but this is a good answer and makes sense doctrinally!

Answer (score 3):

The three virtues of the tree are an instance of what is called the “rule of three”, a literary device which engages the hearer using a pattern that is easy to commit to memory. The significance of three seems to be that the hearer cannot be expected to see a pattern in fewer things. You will find the rule of three used heavily not just throughout the Bible but in any kind of storytelling.

[Christopher Booker points out](http://books.google.com/books?id=qHJj9gOl0j8C) that there are four basic variations on the rule of three: simple, progressive, contrasting, and dialectical.

Using Booker’s organizing principle, we can call the virtues of the tree a progressive three because of the pattern – each is more valuable than the last. This makes it easy to remember the tree and how tempting it was.

The temptations of Christ are another progressive three; the three virtues in Jeremiah and the three worldly desires in 1 John are simple threes.